# I'm using border-left border-right as dividers in my site's navbar. I want to know how I can have them centered in the navbar

Tags: html, css, navbar

The problem I'm having is that I want to have the dividers between the navbar links (Home, About, Blog) centered vertically in the middle of the navbar.
I tried using the padding-top tag but it didn't do anything.

Also, I'm not sure if this is the best way to do what I want, so if there's a better way to make dividers between the navbar links please feel free to make your suggestions because I'm just learning CSS

Here's the code:

https://jsfiddle.net/hntkv9x0/

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="navbar">
<div class="navbarlinks">
<ul>
<li class="navbarlinks"><a class="nav" href="#">HOME</a>
<li class="navbarlinks"><a class="nav" href="#">ABOUT</a>
<li class="navbarlinks"><a class="nav" href="#">BLOG</a>
</ul
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
margin: 0;
padding:0;
background:#FFFFFF;
}

#header {
background: #FFDD00;
height: 150px;
}

#navbar {
background: #000000;
height: 50px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px;
border-bottom: solid #FFDD00;
border-top: solid #FFDD00;
border-width: 5px;
position:relative;
}

ul{list-style-type:none;
text-align: center;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

.navbarlinks {
color: #968517;
font-family:'Ubuntu', sans-serif;line-height:30px;
font-size:15px;
margin-left:5%;
font-style:bold;
}

li {
display: inline;
float:left;
border-right:solid #968517;
border-left:solid #968517;
border-width:1px;
margin:0% -5% 0% 0%;
}

.nav {
display: block;
width:85px;
height:30px;
margin-top:10px;
}

a:link {
text-decoration: none;
color: #968517 background:#000000;
}

a:visited {
color: #968517;
background:#000000;
}

a:hover {
color: #FFDD00;
background:#242113;
}
```

Comment: It's nor quite clear what the final look should be...do you have an image we can aim at?

Comment: I posted a link to the jsfiddle so you can see what it looks like now... @Paulie_D

Comment: I know what it looks like now...what **should** it look like? This ?  - https://jsfiddle.net/s5sazczk/

Comment: Well, surely you saw the dividers that I have in between each of the header links. The problem is that they're stuck to the top. I want them to fill up the entire height of the navbar, or be centered vertically if possible. @Paulie_D

Comment: @Paulie_D Sorry I didnt see the jsfiddle link you posted before. That is exactly what Ihad in mind, except with the header. thank you so much

Comment: Threw that into an answer with another option...also tidied up a bit as you hadn't cleared the floats etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**: Centered vertically

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background: #FFFFFF;
}
#navbar {
  background: #000000;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px;
  border-bottom: solid #FFDD00;
  border-top: solid #FFDD00;
  border-width: 5px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* quick cleafix */
}
li {
  float: left;
  border-right: solid #968517;
  border-left: solid #968517;
  border-width: 1px;
}
.navbarlinks {
  color: #968517;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-style: bold;
}
a.nav {
  display: block;
  width: 85px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
}
a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #968517;
  background: #000000;
}
a:visited {
  color: #968517;
  background: #000000;
}
a:hover {
  color: #FFDD00;
  background: #242113;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <div class="navbarlinks">
    <ul>
      <li class="navbarlinks"><a class="nav" href="#">HOME</a>

      </li>
      <li class="navbarlinks"><a class="nav" href="#">ABOUT</a>

      </li>
      <li class="navbarlinks"><a class="nav" href="#">BLOG</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: the link does not cover the *whole* list item (due to the padding on the `li`

---

**Option 2**: Whole Height

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background: #FFFFFF;
}
#navbar {
  background: #000000;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px;
  border-bottom: solid #FFDD00;
  border-top: solid #FFDD00;
  border-width: 5px;
  position: relative;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* quick cleafix */
}
li {
  float: left;
  border-right: solid #968517;
  border-left: solid #968517;
  border-width: 1px;
}
.navbarlinks {
  color: #968517;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-style: bold;
}
a.nav {
  display: block;
  width: 85px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
}
a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #968517;
  background: #000000;
}
a:visited {
  color: #968517;
  background: #000000;
}
a:hover {
  color: #FFDD00;
  background: #242113;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <div class="navbarlinks">
    <ul>
      <li class="navbarlinks"><a class="nav" href="#">HOME</a>

      </li>
      <li class="navbarlinks"><a class="nav" href="#">ABOUT</a>

      </li>
      <li class="navbarlinks"><a class="nav" href="#">BLOG</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just a question @Paulie_D is there any particular reason you got rid of the big yellow header that was there before?

Comment: It wasn't relevant to the question.

Comment: Design is a subjective thing...not really suited to SO.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `height: 100%;` to the `ul` and `li.navbarlinks` that contains the navbar items.
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hntkv9x0/7/)

Comment: Thanks @Aminesrine I added height: 100%; to my .navbarlinks class and now the dividers fill up the entire height.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/hntkv9x0/8/

You need to apply the margin to the `.navbarlinks` rather than `.nav`